# How to connect two indexes of two tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with some columns such as `id, os_name, os_type` and another table with `id, os_id, date, lang`. How can I connect `id` with `os_id` in phpmyadmin?

I tried to use designer tab, but it pops-up a blank page after I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first define an index by both columns ("structure" section, as I recall); then in "relation view" tab you should define desired link. Note, that both tables should be InnoDB storage-engine.